# The reverse state monad transformer in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml, monads, lazy-evaluation, state-monad

How would you implement the reverse state monad *transformer* in OCaml?

This is a follow-up of the question [The reverse state monad in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943140/the-reverse-state-monad-in-ocaml): I was able to rediscover @Lambdageek's answer by myself after understanding the tricks he or she used (especially the pattern matching of lazy expressions in the module LazyUtils). Then I spent the rest of the day trying to generalize this to the case of the reverse state transformer. But I am stuck because I cannot find how to define the bind. The only solution that I can vaguely imagine would use the mfix of the monad in parameter but this is itself [problematic to define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944117/mfix-for-the-state-monad-in-ocaml) because it leads to looping recursion due to the strict semantics in OCaml.

Comment: Note that even in Haskell, `(RStateT m)` is a `Monad` only when `m` is a `MonadFix`, not just a `Monad`.  So that's a hint that some amount of knot tying will be needed.